# Getting array state is not iterable in react js Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

I have an array state named UpdatedStatus.
I want to append an object into this array whenever a button is clicked, however I keep getting UpdatedStatus in not iterable whenever I click the button

This is how I initialized the state:

```
class AppointmentDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            BookedServices: [],
            Details:[],
            Reject_Modal: false,
            Lab_note: "",
            UpdatedStatus:[],

        };
        this.toggleRejectModal = this.toggleRejectModal.bind(this);
    }
```

This is how I defined the state inside render()

```
 render() {
    const{BookedServices}=this.state;
    const {UpdatedStatus} =this.state.UpdatedStatus;
    const{Details}=this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="page-content">
```

This is how I am trying to set the state:

```
                      <Button 
                       color="primary"
                       size="sm"
                       className="btn-pill mx-2"
                       onClick={() => { this.setState({ UpdatedStatus:[...UpdatedStatus, {BookedServiceStatus: "Accepted", id: item.id }]})
                       console.log(this.state.UpdatedStatus.id)
                                    }}
                                    >
                        Accept
                        </Button>
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is from destructing the `UpdatedStatus` from the `state`. Please replace the snippet with the following
`const {Details, BookedServices, UpdatedStatus} = this.state;`
And inside the console log access the first item of `UpdatedStatus`, using `this.state.UpdatedStatus[0].id`

```
class AppointmentDetails extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      BookedServices: [],
      Details: [],
      Reject_Modal: false,
      Lab_note: '',
      UpdatedStatus: []

    };
    this.toggleRejectModal = this.toggleRejectModal.bind(this);
  }

  render () {
    const { Details, UpdatedStatus, BookedServices } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className='page-content'>

        <Button
          color='primary'
          size='sm'
          className='btn-pill mx-2'
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ UpdatedStatus: [...UpdatedStatus, { BookedServiceStatus: 'Accepted', id: item.id }] });
          }}
        >
          Accept
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: okay I am not getting "not iterable comment anymore" but It says id field is not defined when I try to print  this.state.UpdatedStatus[0].id

Comment: I have edited the original answer. Try the whole code snippet now.

Comment: You are getting the id field not defined because updatedStatus is an empty array.

Comment: Thank you it is working now, however when I try todo this                              this.setState({ UpdatedStatus:[...UpdatedStatus, {BookedServiceStatus: "Accepted", id: item.id }]})                                                 
 console.log(this.state.UpdatedStatus[0])  it prints undefined when I click the Accept button first time, I get the correct values on console when I click accept button again

Comment: It prints undefined as the array is empty at first. So indexing the first item is supposed to give undefined. After clicking on the accept button the array get populated, the first exist and thus indexing the first item doesn't give undefined anymore.

Answer (score 0):

While updating state using its previous value, the callback argument should be used. Otherwise, stale values of state may be taken into account.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

```
this.setState((state)=>
    ({ UpdatedStatus: state.UpdatedStatus.concat({ BookedServiceStatus: 'Accepted', id: item.id })
);
```